# knit pagedown html_resume to pdf with chrome_print produces error

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, pagedown

I would like to produce an HTML and PDF version of a resume with `pagedown::html_resume` and `pagedown::chrome_print`.

I tried running the following code from the example provided by `pagedown`:

```
---
title: "Lijia Yu's resume"
author: Lijia Yu
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  pagedown::html_resume:
    # set it to true for a self-contained HTML page but it'll take longer to render
    self_contained: false
knit: pagedown::chrome_print
---

Aside
================================================================================


![Lijia Yu](https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/895125?s=400&v=4){width=80%}


Contact Info {#contact}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

- <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> lijia.yu@outlook.com
- <i class="fa fa-github"></i> [github.com/yulijia](https://github.com/yulijia)
- <i class="fa fa-phone"></i> +1 000-000-0000
- For more information, please contact me via email.
```

But I receive this error:

```
Error in pagedown::chrome_print("/Users/Person/Documents/r/projects/Untitled.Rmd",  : 
  unused argument (encoding = "UTF-8")
Execution halted
```

If I comment out the line with `chrome_print` I don't get an error.

I tried updating Google Chrome to the latest version (79.0.3945.130) to no avail. I am using `knitr` version 1.25, `pagedown` version 0.5.3, and RStudio version 1.2.1335 on a Mac running Catalina 10.15.2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[When in doubt, try to update your packages.](https://yihui.org/en/2017/05/when-in-doubt-upgrade/) In your case, **pagedown** 0.5.3 is not the latest version. The `encoding` argument [was added](https://github.com/rstudio/pagedown/commit/e2420277f1fe5e087421eee2a03d792a6bb80037) two months ago, and included in the latest CRAN release. So please try to `install.packages('pagedown')`.