# Pagedown resume template does not generate pdf version on knitting

Tags: r, r-markdown, pagedown

I tried to use Yihui Xie's pagedown resume template to produce a resume. The yaml
parameter self_contained was set to true and uncomment knit: pagedown::chrome_print
The full yaml is shown below :
[image]

The template generated the html version of the resume but not pdf. How can I produce the pdf
version of the resume? I have updated all my R packages as suggested [here](https://(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59845106/knit-pagedown-html-resume-to-pdf-with-chrome-print-produces-error%20)).
R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16 ucrt) on Windows 10

Answer (score -1):

You need to change your output to pdf_document

```
output: pdf_document
```

Comment: "output: pdf_document" does not work